# Sending email in Visual C++ without using Common Runtime Support and without using .NET framework

Tags: c++, visual-studio, email

I have a program written in Visual Studio C++ and the last task it needs to complete is to send a data file by email. My program has no Common Runtime Support and the runtime library is set to multi-threaded (/MT). I have sample code for using System::Net::Mail and SMTP Client but I don't want to use it as it relies on .NET, which I want to avoid.
Any alternatives?

Comment: Have you considered creating a socket, having it connect to your mail server, and send its mail directly using SMTP?

Comment: You could try the [Windows MAPI interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAPI).

Comment: I agree with Adrian Mole, you could try to [use MAPI to Send E-Mail](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/messaging/article.php/c5417/Using-MAPI-to-Send-EMail.htm).